# How to select a picker view item in an iOS UI test in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have a picker view with few items: "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Black". In my UI test I need to select a specific item "Green" from it. I am using the  XCTest UI testing APIs that were intruduced with Xcode 7.

[image]

What I managed to do so far is to swipe the whole picker view up in the unit test. It is not ideal because it always changes the picker view to the bottom item (when swiping up).

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
app.pickers.elementAtIndex(0).swipeUp()    
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Selected: Black"].exists)
```

Another but very similar way of changing the picker view is to call `pressForDuration ... thenDragToElement`, which is not what I want.

```
app.pickers.elementAtIndex(0).pressForDuration(0.1, thenDragToElement: someElement)
```

When I use the UI test **record** function it does not record the picker view scrolling events. It does record when I tap on picker view items:

```
app.pickerWheels["Green"].tap()
```

but that does not actually work when the test is run (probably because it needs to scroll the picker view first before tapping).

Here is the demo app with the test.

https://github.com/exchangegroup/PickerViewTestDemo

### Update

It is now possible to select a picker view since Xcode 7.0 beta 6 .

```
app.pickerWheels["Green"].adjustToPickerWheelValue("Yellow")
```

Comment: really want to know the answer. I am facing the similar issue. for sure we can't rely on the generated code for pickers.

Comment: Not yet supported in OSX. Ugh.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As noted in the question's update, Xcode 7 Beta 6 added support for interacting with pickers. The newly added method `-adjustToPickerWheelValue:` should be used to select items on a `UIPickerView`.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
app.pickerWheels.element.adjustToPickerWheelValue("Yellow")
```

Here's a [GitHub repo with a working example](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UIPickerViewTester). And some [more information in a blog post I wrote](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/).

Comment: There is an open rdar about this http://www.openradar.me/22918650 How does this work?

Comment: `.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "foo")` is not working for me

Answer (score 20):

If there are multiple wheels, an easy way to select items it is like this:

precondition: it's a date picker (UIDatePicker), swift language

```
    app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(0).adjustToPickerWheelValue("March")
    app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(1).adjustToPickerWheelValue("13")
    app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(2).adjustToPickerWheelValue("1990")
```

where: index "0" is month, "1" is day, "2" is year

Comment: be careful with localization when you use absolute index. The month and day wheels could be different depending which local the device has (us and german locals for exmaple have different layouts)

Comment: This is not working. I am always getting: "UI Testing Failure - Internal error: unable to find current value 'Something, 1 of 3' in possible values thing, thing2, thing3 for the picker wheel "Something, 1 of 3" PickerWheel"

Comment: : index "0" is month, "1" is day, "2" is year... Works for all country configurations?

Comment: This will not work outside of english. In danish, the value for march is "marts", and in french it is "mars". The example code will fail in both.

I have not tested the order, but both languages mentioned are ordered day-month-year, instead of month-day-year, so that is potentially an issue as well

Comment: app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: NSLocalizedString("January", comment: ""))

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4 version of **@Joao_dche**'s answer

```
app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "March")
app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 1).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "13")
app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 2).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "1990")
```

Comment: This is the same in Swift 4

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-C** Version of **@Joao_dche**'s Answer

Using UIDatePicker with XCTest for UI Testing:

```
    XCUIElementQuery *datePickersQuery = app.datePickers;
    [datePickersQuery.pickerWheels.allElementsBoundByIndex[0] adjustToPickerWheelValue:@"May"];
    [datePickersQuery.pickerWheels.allElementsBoundByIndex[1] adjustToPickerWheelValue:@"13"];
    [datePickersQuery.pickerWheels.allElementsBoundByIndex[2] adjustToPickerWheelValue:@"2017"];

    XCUIElement *doneButton = app.buttons[@"Done"];
    [doneButton.firstMatch tap];
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31458432/8511548) working great on iOS 11, but doesn't work for me on iOS 10.3.1 [Xcode 9.2]**

I use custom views (labels actually) as picker rows and unfortunately gorgeous Joe's answer ***doesn't work*** for me on iOS 10.3.1 while ***working perfectly*** on iOS 11. So I had to use

```
app.pickerWheels["X, Y of Z"].swipeUp()
```

where

```
X is my label's text.
Y is row position in picker view. Position number starts with 1, not zero.
Z is number of values in picker view.
```

So in my case this command looks like

```
app.pickerWheels["1st, 1 of 28"].swipeUp()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of most popular post for select pickervie(UIPickerView)

If you want to select state/date from picker view. You can try following swift 3 code.

```
 XCUIApplication().tables.pickerWheels["AK"].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "MA")
```

PickerWheels pick from AK and set the target state.

XCUIApplication().tables.pickerWheels[**"Starting Point"** "].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "**Target Place**")

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I used below code to identify the element displayed now in the picker wheel.

## To Find an element in picker

```
let valueSelected = algorithmsPicker.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).value as! String
```

## To select a value in the picker wheel:

```
 algorithmsPicker.pickerWheels[valueSelected].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "BubbleSort")
```