# Not able to get adjustToPickerWheelValue in xctest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I am trying to select a value in picker wheel but every time I type `[app.pickerWheels.adjustToPickerWheelValue[@"Test"]];`
 Xcode says

> Property 'adjustToPickerWheelValue' not found on object of type 'XCUIElementQuery'

How to resolve this issue ?

Here is the link i followed till now [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257409/how-to-select-a-picker-view-item-in-an-ios-ui-test-in-xcode)

UIElement Tree [image]

Answer (score 0):

`adjustToPickerWheelValue` is a method on XCUIElement, but you are using it on an XCUIElementQuery.

To get an XCUIElement, you must specify which picker wheel you want (even if there is only one).

```
let pickerWheel = app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(0)
pickerWheel.adjustToPickerWheelValue("some value")
```

Comment: Please also note that there are known issues with the adjustToPickerWheelValue method: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16104