# Is there a way to get the string value of a picker wheel that is an XCUIElement?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I know that this exists:
`func adjust(toPickerWheelValue pickerWheelValue: String)`, but I'm not trying to adjust the value. I want to make sure that the value is the string that I'm expecting after I've moved it.

I tried doing `.value` on the picker wheel element, but it's giving me an `Any` type with the string that I need in there, plus some extra stuff.

Let's say the printout of the screen is this:

```
Attributes: Application, pid: 64445, label: ‘App’
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x60000263a150, pid: 64445, label: ‘App’
    Window (Main), 0x600002639110, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
      Other, 0x6000026396c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
        Picker, 0x600002639040, {{0.0, 352.0}, {320.0, 216.0}}
            PickerWheel, 0x600002639520, {{0.0, 314.5}, {103.0, 291.0}}, value: 0 hours
            PickerWheel, 0x600002639380, {{108.0, 314.5}, {103.0, 291.0}}, value: 13 min
```

I'll print out `app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).value` in the console and get this

```
Optional<Any>
    - some : 0 hours
```

I explicitly only want the `0 hours` so I can assert that the picker wheel says that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since I was having the same problem I found your question here. And now I found a solution as well from here: [How to select a picker view item in an iOS UI test in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257409/how-to-select-a-picker-view-item-in-an-ios-ui-test-in-xcode/47467241#47467241) (the last answer).

It is possible to cast the value to String like this:

```
let value = app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).value as! String
```

This gave me the correct value to continue.

Hope I was able to help, since your question helped me as well and it made me sign up here to give the answer.